# Navigate to the timeline (to the card with bundleId) from within an application

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk, google-mirror-api

I have a Glass application that is activated by a voice command. The user requests a product and the request is then passed on to a node.js server, which handles the bulk logic of my application. When the node server is done, it builds some HTML templates that it passes on to the Mirror API, which then puts those cards into the timeline of the Glass app.

Now the problem I have is this:
When a user requests something from within the application, he just stays within that application but the cards from the Mirror API are put onto the timeline.

Is it possible to navigate the user from within the application to the timeline item that has just been inserted?

As I build the Mirror API timeline item, I know ahead of time what the bundleId will be on the timeline, so can I use that somehow to navigate to that item on the timeline?

I've had a look here on Stackoverflow, the Glass forums and the official documentation and couldn't see anything that would help.. Anybody here have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Currently the only way for forcing a specific card to show in the timeline is by using a `LiveCard` (https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/reference/com/google/android/glass/timeline/LiveCard). Live cards will automatically be given focus when published and you can force the timeline to give your card focus after publishing by calling `LiveCard.navigate()`.

So unfortunately unless you want to change some of the fundamentals of your app, this isn't going to be much help.

Though from the sounds of it, you may be able to use a `LiveCard` to show what is returned from your server. If you want to perform inserts via the mirror API, this could still be done in addition.